# setText firebase TimeStamp to a TextView in Android

Tags: java, firebase, timestamp, simpledateformat, settext

I'm reading data from cloud firestore one of which is a TimeStamp. So how I can set that TimeStamp to a TextView in an activity in SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Android? As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Hey @Malay! Did you try my answer, did it solve your problem?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit yeah it did. tahnk u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first turn the `timeStamp` to actual date format using a code like this:

```java
private String getDate(long time) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    return date;
}
```

Now you can set this date to textView using `setText()` method, using a code like below:

```java
textView.setText(getDate(timestamp));
```

Here `timeStamp` can be the time stamp that you retrieve from your Firebase cloud Firestore.